# How to parse HTML that is being returned by JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to parse HTML that is being returned by JSON object.

[image: Check below image to see how exactly the html being returned]

Image URL : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRbpW.jpg

How can i parse only  "Deal Price" from above HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame that the price isn't well defined in an HTML element.

Probably your best bet is a bit of dirty regex string extraction.  Something like the following should work:

```
var matches = aGoldboxdeals[5].content.match(/Deal Price: \$([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/);
if (matches){
   var dealPrice = matches[1];
   // do something with the price here parseFloat etc...
} else {
   // couldn't parse the price
}
```

It may be better to first parse the fragment in jQuery to extract a more specific element first but something like above should work.